# Creating a parameter which indicates adding values to only part of the elements in a Matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

alpha represents the proportion of elements in OldMatrix can be from 0 to 1.

How can I create a create a parameter like alpha that indicates that I only want to add an integer like data to only a proportion of the elements in matrix such as OldMatrix ?

[Image Matrix Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pZNO.png)

Comment: It sounds like you want [index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) for a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this function, it seems to work on your example. Let me know.

```
def transform(matrix, proportion, data):
    new_matrix = []
    for i in range(int(len(matrix) * proportion)):
        new_matrix.append(map(lambda x: x+data, matrix[i]))

    if len(new_matrix) < len(matrix):
        diff =  len(matrix) - len(new_matrix)
        new_matrix.append(matrix[diff:])

    return new_matrix
```

By the way, I'm assuming that the value of new matrix 1 at `[2][3]` in your .png when alpha=0.5, is meant to be 12 right?